# Spring intercept url pattern for exact match

Tags: spring-security

I've a two url patterns, one is `/common/` and `/common/**` . What I want is, if the url pattern is   `/common/` I need to block that url . and if the url pattern is   `/common/**`   then I need to allow that url. I want some thing like below. path-type can be regex or ant.

```
 <security:http >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/common/" access="denyAll" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/common/**" access="ROLE_TEST" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>
```

Please help how to solve this problem.

Comment: whats the behaviour if you use it the way you have mentioned above ?

Comment: if I hit the url for ex: https://test.com/common/ the directory structure is coming. I want to block it.

Comment: test.com/common/ or test.com/common ?

Comment: sorry. test.com/common/